# MVC - Ordered List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to order the following list by descending but I can't seem to figure out how it is done:

```
var cust = item.Profiles.Select(c => new
               {
                   id = c.CustId,
                   Name = c.Name
               }).ToList();
ViewBag.Customers = new MultiSelectList(cust, "id", "Name");
```

This is what I have already tried:

```
var cust = item.Profiles.Select(c => new
               {
                   id = c.CustId,
                   Name = c.Name.OrderByDescending();
               }).ToList();
ViewBag.Customers = new MultiSelectList(cust, "id", "Name");
```

This is how the list is displayed on my view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Customers, new { @class = "form-control", id = "lstCustomer" })
```

Note: I am trying to sort the list in alphabetical order

Comment: ``item.Profiles.Select(c => new
                {
                    id = c.CustId,
                    Name = c.Name

                }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Name)``

Comment: `var cust = item.Profiles.OrderByDescending(c => c.Name).Select(....`

Comment: Thanks Stephen that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cust = item.Profiles.Select(c => new
                {
                    id = c.CustId,
                    Name = c.Name

                }).OrderByDescending(c=>c.Name).ToList();
```

Or

```
 var cust = item.Profiles.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Name).Select(c => new
            {
                id = c.CustId,
                Name = c.Name

            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

```
var cust = item.Profiles.Select(c => new
            {
                id = c.CustId,
                Name = c.Name
            }).OrderByDescending(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

Or More Elegant (Query Syntax):

```
var cust = (from c in item.Profiles
            orderby c.Name
            select new
            {
                id = c.CustId,
                Name = c.Name
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the same thing with query syntax:

```
  var cust = (from c in item.Profiles
              orderby c.Name descending
              select new
                     {
                        id = c.CustId,
                        Name = c.Name
                     }
              ).ToList();
```